# How to end the touchesBegan function in swift spritekit

Tags: xcode, swift, touchesbegan

I am building a game in swift spriteKit, I am working with a TouchesBegan function and a DidBeginContact function, when the DidBeginContact function is called I want the TouchesBegan function to be inactive. I searched for tutorials on how to accomplish this but to no avail.. Some help would be legit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think there is a way to turn it off by default.

Just create a bool

```
var touchesAllowed = true
```

Than in your didBeginContact method you set it to false

```
touchesAllowed = false
```

and set it to true whenever you want touches allowed again

```
touchesAllowed = true
```

Finally in your touches method right at the beginning you check for it

```
guard touchesAllowed else { return }
/// rest of your touch code
```

Comment: I KNEW it had to be that simple! Thanks crashoverride. :)

Comment: My pleasure, happy coding